# my code executes, but does not get any output

Tags: java, eclipse

I am Jordan a high school student, i recently got a coding challenge/homework that goes like this: you have the numbers 1 to 18 and you need to find combinations of flowing numbers that are equal when you put an equal sign in between them and a plus sign between every number, for example: 1+2=3 or 
4+6+7+8=9+10+11
I need to find six of these combinations but my program will not find any, please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}; 
    boolean check;
    int s = A[1];
    int e = A[s+1]; 
    int eq= A[s+1]; 
    for(e=s+1;e==A[17];e++){
        for(eq=s+1;eq==e;eq++){
            if(Integer.sum(s, eq-1) == e) {
                check = true;
              } 
            if(check = true) {
                System.out.println("start number is ---" + s + "equal number is ---" + eq + "end number is ---" + e);
```

i expect to get a starting point where to put the equal and an ending point for six combinations but instead i get nothing

Comment: I don't think your `s`, `e` and `s+1` are in the right place...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: First of all, arrays start at 0. so `s` should be `A[0]`

Comment: Where are all of your closing `}` for both `for` loops, and the last `if` statement?  You use `{` to open them but I don't see the end.

Comment: Rethink why you used `e==A[17]` and `eq==e` and recheck how the `for` loop is structured.

Comment: Also, instead of `if(check = true) {` you probably meant `if(check == true) {`, otherwise the if statement is executed always.

Comment: @Jannik can even just be `if(check)`

Comment: @Nexevis yes, i just wanted to point out the difference between `=` and `==` :D